# How to use my keystore in my application for HttpsUrlConnection?

Tags: android

I wanted to make secure connection, for that am using HttpsUrlConnection in my application.
I also had an CA certificate for the URL which am using. and also as per the suggestions from other sites, have created keystore named mystore.bks for that certificate.

The problem is that, am making this connection part in a seperate thread. I want sample piece of code to use this keystore with HttpsUrlConnection within a thread.

Please answer how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the standard way.

Get a hash of the keystore, and then send it along in the http request.

Add the same hash on the server, and then check it when the request is sent.

Comment: I have tried with the methods explained in the below link but it doesn't worked for me...http://vafer.org/blog/20061010073725/..... please send me some sample working code..